# Can't set a variable to true in PHP

Tags: php, variables, boolean

I'm making a PHP script where I use a class boolean variable, but for some reason, when I want to set it to `true`, it doesn't work :/

```
<?php


class TinyFram {



    private $urlMatched;


    public function get($url, $method){

        $urlR = str_replace('/', '\/', $url);
        $urlR = '^' . $urlR . '\/?$';

        if (preg_match("/$urlR/i", $reqURI, $rMatch)) {
            $this->urlMatched = true; // I SET IT TO TRUE HERE
            $method($rMatch);
        } 
        if(!$this->urlMatched) {
            echo var_dump($this->urlMatched); // BUT HERE IT SHOWS AS FALSE
            notFound($rMatch);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

What I'm doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: You only do the `var_dump` when the second `if` conditional passes, but you have that condition as `(!$this->urlMatched)`.  So I'm not sure why you're surprised!

Comment: Also, you probably want to `preg_quote` your `$url`...

Comment: Maybe my RegExp are wrong too. But IDK why it it doesn't sets it as `true`, because `preg_match` matchs and `$method($rMatch);` gets called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your preg_match is not matching, so the variable never gets set to true.

Comment: It does get called, because `$method($rMatch);` gets called

Answer (score 1):

The `var_dump` is in a conditional that check whether $this->urlMatched is a falsy value (false, 0, '', null). Of course it will show up as false then.

btw: `var_dump` does not need to have an echo in front of it.